# Can I embed playN game into GWT built website?

Tags: gwt, playn

I was wondering if I could build browser-based game taking the advantages of the GWT and playN both since both are compiled same way to HTML/JS?

I realise that simple embeding game window into GWT built website should be possible, but I'd like it to be one entity, which means I'd like **to comunicate** between playN and GWT, and possibly use the same server.

Is it possible or I'm rather dreaming?

Comment: Have you tried running them both on the same page? You would have to compile them separately so the only communication you would have would be via javascript. So simply create a Javascript method to dispatch messages JSNI functions in your GWT and PlayN code

Comment: I extracted out the HTML/JS part form the war file, dropping jar files and some binary stuff, and I could host that statically. Note however that so far we had to chop off OAuth and DataStore functionality from the HTML port since it doesn't survive the GWT compilation phase. So it's a limited demo.